# Any easier way to flush aggregator to GCS at the end of google dataflow pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am using `Aggregator` to log some runtime stats of dataflow job and I want to flush them to either GCS or BQ when the pipeline completes (or each transformer completes).

Currently I am doing it by beyond using `Aggregator` also creating side output by utilizing tupleTag at the same time and flush the side output PCollection.
However i am wondering whether might there by any other handy ways to flush the aggregators themselves directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method of using a side output PCollection should produce semantically equivalent results to using an Aggregator. (For example, both Aggregators and side outputs will not include duplicate values when a bundle fails and has to be retried.) The main difference is that partial results for Aggregators are available during pipeline execution in the monitoring UI and programmatically.

Within Java, you can use [PipelineResult.getAggregatorValues()](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/PipelineResult#getAggregatorValues-com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.transforms.Aggregator-). If you get the PipelineResult from the [non-blocking]`DataflowPipelineRunner`, that will let you query aggregators as the job runs. If you use the `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner`, `Pipeline.run()` blocks and you won't get the PipelineResult until after the job completes.

There's also [commandline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/dataflow-command-line-intf) support: `gcloud alpha dataflow metrics tail JOB_ID`

Comment: @ Frances is there any example on how to use PipelineResult.getAggregatorValues()? Since this method takes instance of Aggregator class as a parameter, what would be the suggested approach? Is it having Aggregator instance as a DoFn implementation field, and getter for it used to retrieve its value a standard approach? Tnx